# Is there an online store where I can buy CiviCRM stickers, t-shirts, books, etc? Should there be?

Tags: amazon

I'd like to buy CiviCRM stickers, CiviCon t-shirts, books about CiviCRM and other CiviCRM stuff.

Is there an online store where I can buy such things? If not, should CiviCRM.org create one?

Thanks for your thoughts!

Answer (score 1):

I can buy the new, second edition of **[Using CiviCRM](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1783281456)** by Erik Hommel, Joe Murray and Brian Shaughnessy on Amazon.com .

CiviCRM.org could [set up a store on **CafePress.com**](http://www.cafepress.com/+all+gifts) to sell t-shirts, stickers and other stuff. I would buy some stuff that way.